# Get count of each unique column field by date from mongodb data

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I would like to get count of each unique column field by date from mongodb data. Please see the example below.

Here I need result to display Monthly data of each subject with total count of each subject. I have tried grouping but couldn't get the actual output needed.

Student collection:

```json
[{
   _id: uniqueId,   
   Date: '201507', // Year and month
   Subject: 'Maths',
},
{
   _id: uniqueId,   
   Date: '201507', // Year and month
   Subject: 'Physics'
},
{
   _id: uniqueId,   
   Date: '201508', // Year and month
   Subject: 'Maths'
},
{
   _id: uniqueId,   
   Date: '201507', // Year and month
   Subject: 'Maths'
}
]
```

The output will be

```json
[
  {
    Date: 201507,
    Subject: {
                Maths: 2, // count
                Physics: 1
             }
  },
  {
    Date: 201508,
    Subject: {
                Maths: 1, // count                
             }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this aggregate query:

- First `$group` by `Subject` and `Date` as `_id` and creating a field called `total` where get the total times a subject is for a date.
- Then `$project` to create the object with keys `k` and `v` (used later to transform an array to an object).
- `$group` again by date to get all subjects for each date.
- `$project` using [`$arrayToObject`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/) to transform the array into an object.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": {
        "Subject": "$Subject",
        "Date": "$Date"
      },
      "total": {
        "$sum": 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 0,
      "Date": "$_id.Date",
      "Subject": {
        "k": "$_id.Subject",
        "v": "$total"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$Date",
      "Subject": {
        "$push": "$Subject"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 0,
      "Subject": {
        "$arrayToObject": "$Subject"
      },
      "Date": "$_id"
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/JQYBW-fXWb6)